# Split Delivery : Drupal Commerce future : 2 qty in differnt Address : Single Order in Multiple Address

Tags: forms, commerce, entities, hooks

I want to create split delivery functionality in Drupal 7. I want to split qty in differnt delivery address.ex
Like Product A have 2 qty .I want to deliver 1 qty to my friend house and 1 to  my Address.Please give some suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

There is no module offering split shipping like this out of the box. The Commerce Shipment module does support making multiple shipments out of the products on an order, but it requires custom code to tell it on what basis the order ought to be split. To date, this has only included support for line item based splits for pre-orders, so you'd need to develop a user interface for selecting products / entering their addresses and the ability to split up individual line items based on quantity.

Comment: Thank you Ryan for your response,i will message you,if there any help required in any stage of development.Currently i took line items details in Form and using Ajax to split line item.In click on Ajax element i took clone of qty and default adress .Don't know its right way to do or not